# Hiding metasploit APK after first launch

Tags: android, metasploit

How can I hide metasploit APK after first launch? I know there is a command for it in meterpreter but I want it to hide itself when it is first launched. Before adding `hide_app_icon` command to meterpreter app used to be hidden automatically. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply type
`hide_app_icon` after putting the `exploit` command
and it will listen after it redirects to meterpreter it will auto type the command you just typed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).